# How to set an environment variable during a Cypress test?

Tags: cypress

I am looking to re-use a particular value across multiple step definitions in my Cypress/Cucumber test.

I was thinking of using a normal variable, but the problem is that the step definitions are stored in different files.

So I am wondering if I could assign the value to an environment variable & reference that in the other file.

I was trying to do something like `Cypress.env('myUsername') = 'testUser'`, but I get this lint error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cypress environment variables can be set during a test by [passing in the desired value as the second argument](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env#Arguments).

```js
Cypress.env('HOST', 'asdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, `env` API syntax should look like something below:

```
 - Cypress.env()
 - Cypress.env(name)
 - Cypress.env(name, value)
 - Cypress.env(object)
```

In your case the following will work

```
Cypress.env('myUsername', 'testUser')
```